# Unable to create Tensorflow session: "Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal n"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, conda

I set up a Conda environment with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. After installing Tensorflow 1.4 with seemingly no problems, now I can't create a session for some reason. Running the following lines of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
```

produces the following error:

```
2018-07-19 14:56:46.660399: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.8095
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 7.92GiB freeMemory: 6.83GiB
2018-07-19 14:56:46.780827: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:170] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 1: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; total memory reported: 8508145664
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/.conda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1482, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/me/.conda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 622, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/home/me/.conda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

I can fix it by choosing the GPU to use like below, but that's not what I want to do:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

It doesn't make sense to me that this should invoke a `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY`, especially seeing how there is more than enough free memory at the beginning. Also, I could run Tensorflow 1.4 with no issued in Python 3.6 earlier on the same machine.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: One possible reason is that Tensorflow pre-allocates GPU memory (I read it is default at 70% somewhere, but I am not sure if that is correct) no matter how small the variable you created is. Choosing the GPU to work with seems to alleviate this problem.